# Javascript copy input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Guys I want to copy input value yeah on button click But nothing work. Please Help!!

```
<script>
  function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
  }
</script>   

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="myvalue"  id="myvalue" value="YEAH" readonly  />

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard('#myvalue')">Copy myvalue</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @anddy but i want to copy input value :( how to do this ??

Comment: In clipboard or in another element?

Comment: means input value yeah i want to copy this :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
    var textBox = document.getElementById("myvalue");
    textBox.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="myvalue"  id="myvalue" value="YEAH" readonly  />

     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy myvalue</button>
```

Comment: Done :) Thanks alot

Comment: nice clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

Code if you want to copy input text to ClipBoard.

```
//HTML
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="myvalue"  id="myvalue" value="YEAH" readonly  />
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard();">Copy myvalue</button>


//SCRIPT For ClipBoard Copy
 <Script>
    function copyToClipboard() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById("myvalue");
        textBox.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
    }
</Script>



//For local storage variable copy
<Script>
    function copyToStorage() {
        var textBox = document.getElementById("myvalue");
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

            var textBox_value=textBox.value;
            localStorage.setItem("textBox_value", textBox_value);
         } else {
               alert("Sorry your browser does not support this script");
           }
    }
</Script>

   // Also there one to use an element like hidden to store the value for same page life.
```

Answer (score 0):

document.execCommand() is now obsolete,
the alternative is Clipboard API, via navigator.clipboard. Per MDN Web Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API):

```js
function copyToClipboard() {
  var textBox = document.getElementById("myvalue");
  console.log(textBox.value)
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(textBox.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="myvalue"  id="myvalue" value="YEAH YEAH" readonly  />
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy myvalue</button>
```